# Can not Install NPM along side with the ROS melodic?

Tags: node.js, ros

I am using ROS melodic for my current project but I need to install nodejs for my college work in ubuntu 18.04. When I install nodejs by using the following commands

`sudo apt install nodejs`  
`sudo apt install npm`
 
it gives me an error like this.
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MdmV.png)

So I installed that dependency but after installing that dependency my ros packages removed.
 How can I install the npm without losing the ROS melodic?

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: You might want to use the documented way to install Node : https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md#debinstall (from https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions). Alternatively, you can use [NVM](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) if you think you might have to switch between Node versions some time

Comment: thank you for your response, i actually tried with the documented way and i installed nodejs without any error but the problem remains for the NPM, it remove my ROS packages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found something on the internet that take me to the solution,
I installed python virtual environment

https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-create-python-virtual-environments-on-ubuntu-18-04/

in that virtual environment I installed nodeenv with the help of pip

https://pypi.org/project/nodeenv/#id73

I created node.js virtual environment in which I installed the NPM without getting any error.
[image]

And we can also install nodeenv with the global environment too!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and [solutions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1088662/npm-depends-node-gyp-0-10-9-but-it-is-not-going-to-be-installed) were deleting whole ros melodic.

found the solution as follows:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge nodejs npm
```

after this command if you installed nodejs it's going to be deleted.

enable the NodeSource repository by running the following curl command:

```
$ curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo -E bash -
```

then:

```
$ sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

the nodejs package contains both the node and npm binaries.